# Using multi-markers with multi info-windows

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, dom-events, infowindow

I have an array of info-windows corresponding to an array of markers.
Now, I have a problem, I use the below code to generate an info-window, when clicking on the marker all the markers disappear unless one, also when I click on that marker there is no info-window come out.
What is the wrong with my code ? or what shall I do?

Any answer will be very appreciated.

This code is inside a for loop:

```
infoWindoArray[i][j] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                      content:"Lat: "+this.position.lat() + "\nLng: " + this.position.lng() + "\n"+ this.customInfo,
                });

                google.maps.event.addListener(AllMarkers[i][j], 'click', (function(x) {
                    return function() {infoWindoArray[i][j].open(map,AllMarkers[i][j]);}
                })(x));
```

Edited: I added the whole for loop to be more clear:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < ArrayOfAllFilesData.length-1; i++) {//to select certain file.
            var myarr = ArrayOfAllFilesData[i+1];

            AllMarkers[i] = new Array();
            for (var j=0; j < myarr.length; j++) {
                var marker_center = new google.maps.LatLng(myarr[j][0],myarr[j][1]);

                AllMarkers[i][j] = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: marker_center,
                    customInfo: "Number of encounters: "+myarr[j][2],
                    title:'Click to zoom',
                    visible:true,
                });
                AllMarkers[i][j].setMap(map);

            };
        };
    }
```

Comment: It's more usual (and economical) to have just one infowindow and to change its content each time a marker is clicked.

Comment: But I need multi-info-windows appear to compare between there data.

Comment: Ah ok, though it would still be more economical not to have one infowindow per marker if you can avoid it. Maybe you can get away with just two or three infowindows?

Comment: I don't think so, but I want to know How can I do it even if they are only three infowindows ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a compromise approach with one infoWindow per maker but the infowindows are not created in advance. Instead, they are created on-demand, as each marker is clicked.

This way, infoWindows that will never be seen are not created. And once created, each infoWindow will be reused if the user revisits its marker.

Outside the nested i/j loops :

```
var AllMarkers = [];//Not necessary unless used elsewhere

function clickMarker_closure(arr) {
    return function() {
        if(!this.infoWin) {
            this.infoWin = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: [
                    "Lat: " + this.position.lat(),
                    "Lng: " + this.position.lng(),
                    "Number of encounters: " + arr[2]
                ].join("\n")
            });
        }
        this.infoWin.open(map, this);
    };
}
```

And the nested i/j loops :

```
for (var i=0; i<ArrayOfAllFilesData.length-1; i++) {//to select certain file.
    var myarr = ArrayOfAllFilesData[i+1],
        marker;
    AllMarkers[i] = [];//necessary?
    for (var j=0; j < myarr.length; j++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(myarr[j][0], myarr[j][1]),
            title: 'Click to zoom',
            visible: true,
        });
        AllMarkers[i][j] = marker;//necessary?
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', clickMarker_closure(myarr[j]));
    }
}
```

Users will be unaware that the infoWindows are created on-demand.

**Edit 1**

- Edited above with better knowledge of the structure of the i/j loops and to simplify the closure's reference to its data and marker.
- infoWindoArray is no longer required.

Comment: I understand our code and I got benefit from it, but unfortunately the problem still the same. :(
Only the fist marker still appear and the other disappear, also this one doesn't popup any info-window :(

Comment: OK, with better knowledge of the construction of the i/j loops, I have revised the answer. I've never worked with multiple infoWindows, so there may be something I don't understand, so let me know how it goes.

Comment: ya, I get the point and recognize the wrong. :)
Thanks very mach Beetroot for your help and your experience. :D

Comment: I could have included more comments for you. Do you get the use of `this.infoWin`, ie. a custom property of each marker, providing a reference to its infoWindow? That simplifies things considerably.